# How to output sql query to csv file and make is accessible

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

Is there a way to output the result of an SQL query to a CSV file and make it accessible?

I output an SQL result from MySQL to CSV file but the file was not accessible

```
select date,str_location, lc_prof\
from clean_store\
where date='2019-11-26'\
order by lc_prof into outputfile 'location_wise_profit.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES 
TERMINATED  BY '\n';
```

it ran successfully but the output file cannot be accessed by other applications.

It shows **permission denied** when trying to access it by other applications.

[image]

Comment: What is the permission of the directory to which you are writing? Like.. is this a directory permission issue or a file permission issue?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? The permissions on the output fie changed in 8.0.17.

Comment: What does `ls -l location_wise_profit.csv` show?

Comment: @Barmar it gives this -rw-r----- 1 999 999 150 Jul  8 19:37

Comment: See the note about permissions [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html)

Comment: @Barmar please i don't seem to see anything that can help..do i need to add a parameter when outputting it to a file?

Comment: What it's saying is that this is normal in 8.0.17. Only processes with the same user or group as the mysql daemon can read these files.

Comment: ok I have created an input folder on my windows and I have a docker container that has MySQL,  and airflow.. the input folder was mounted on airflow and MySQL containers. how do I go about what you just said.. I have been on this for over 7hrs. I really need rescuing